# Telerik Grid shows outside telerik Tabstrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I'm having a problem displaying a grid in the tab. The grid works fine above the tab strip.

Does anyone know how fix the problem so Its in the tab?

Its a MVC project with razor vbhtml

The way I'm getting the contents is

```
     With Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("department-edit").Items(Sub(x)

                                                                     x.Add.Text("Test").Content(TabContacts().ToHtmlString)
                                                                     x.Add.Text("Info").Content(TabInfo().ToHtmlString()).Selected(False)

                                                             End Sub)
    .Render()
End With 


    @helper TabContacts()

        @<table class="Content">
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Code 

                        With Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.DepartmentContacts)

                            .Name("departmentcontact-grid")

                            .DataKeys(Sub(keys) keys.Add(Function(x) x.Id))

                            .DataBinding(Sub(dataBinding)
                                                 dataBinding.Ajax().Select("List", "Department", New With {.departmentId = Model.Id})
                                         End Sub)

                            .Columns(Sub(cols)
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.DisplayOrder1).Width(100).Centered()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.ContactName).Width(500).ReadOnly()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.ContactNumber).Width(100).Centered()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.ContactExt).Width(100).Centered()

                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.Email).Width(100).Centered()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.Location).Width(100).Centered()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.IsActive).Width(100).Centered()
                                             cols.Bound(Function(x) x.IsMainContact).Width(100).Centered()


                                     End Sub)

                            .Pageable(Sub(settings) settings.PageSize(10).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                            .Render()
                        End With

                    End Code

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>    
  End helper
```

Thanks